# gzip and git diff and s3

Tags: git, bash, jenkins

I need to get a list of files that have changed since the last deployment (git diff), gzip those files, and send those files to S3. I need to get all of the css files and gzip them, then I need to get all of the html files, gzip them, and all of the JS files and gzip them. Only if they changed since the last commit.

I can get the commit hash from the last deployment easily. I also have the commit hash from the current deployment.

Here's the code that I have that gzips all of the css files. I would like to modify this code to only gzip all of the css files that changed

```
find . -iname '*.css' -exec gzip -9 {} \; -exec mv {}.gz {} \;
```

Here's sample code that I have to aws sync all of the html files (I have separate aws sync commands for css, js, html files because I need different content type and content encoding and caching parameters for them). I would like to modify this code to only aws sync the html files that changed

```
aws s3 sync . s3://test --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=31536000" --exclude "*" --include "*.html"
```

How do I tie this code to git diff? To only gzip the files that have changed? and to only aws sync the files that have changed (the files in the list of files that git diff returns)?

Also, I want to copy some files that git diff returns to a separate directory. For example, all files in the images/ folder needs to be copied to the StaticAssets/ directory. How do I get a list of files that have changed and that are in the images folder and copy them to a separate folder?

I want to use bash to do this.

So I know I can use the `git diff --name-only` command. My question is, how can I use that command in bash to do the following:

- Gzip all of **changed** css files, Gzip all of changed js files, Gzip all of the changed html files separately (note that the css files may be in a directory that is within another directory). I need to retrieve all of the css files in the parent directory. So if the parent directory has folder test and that folder has another folder called test1 with a css file called test.css I need to be able to gzip that css file even though its 2 directories down
- AWS Sync all **changed** js files, AWS sync all of changed css files separately
- Copy files that have **changed** and that are in the images/ folder to a another directory

Comment: Do you have a tag or some other marker for the last deployment? Do you have a copy of the deployed files?

Comment: I have the git commit hash of the last deployment.

Comment: Are you asking for the `git diff` command you need here? Are you asking for how to hook that output up to `gzip` and `s3 sync` (or whatever)? Do you have any code as an attempt at this?

Comment: heres the code I have that gzips the files 
find . -iname '*.css' -exec gzip -9 {} \; -exec mv {}.gz {} \; but I want to tie this code to git diff

Comment: That `s3 sync` command won't sync any `.css` files (assuming `--include` works the way I would assume). Also isn't `s3 sync` smart enough to only sync changed files by default?

Comment: I run git clone at the start of the jenkins build. git clone changes the modification times of the files so aws sync syncs the same files over and over again

Comment: Getting the list of changed files from `git diff` is as simple as `git diff --name-only "$revision"` (optionally with `-z` for safety for files with newlines in them but it requires a bit of extra parsing). Then you use that to feed your loop and sync command.

Comment: I know that. I know I can use git diff. I'm asking how can I use git diff to feed to my sync command, to copy files from in one folder (images) to another, and to gzip css, image, and js files.

Comment: That's why I asked (in my second comment) what, specifically, was the question here. If you look on this site there are any number of questions that use a `while` loop to read input from a stream (like what `git diff` can give you) and then use that to fill an array or perform other actions. That's what you need to do here.

Comment: while loop won't work because I want to get all of the css files and gzip them, then I want to get all of the html files and gzip them, then I want to get all of the files that changed and that are in the images/ folder and copy them to a separate folder, then I want to aws sync all of the css files that changed

Comment: I have no earthly idea why you think a loop won't let you do that. You can gzip as you go or collect the names into N arrays by type and then operate on them by-type later ... or anything else you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

> Gzip all of changed css files, Gzip all of changed js files, Gzip all of the changed html files separately

The basic way to get a list of changed files is `git diff --name-only`.

You can filter that list to get only CSS files with `grep '.css$' -`.  `-` says to read from STDIN instead of a file.

You can pass that list `gzip` using `xargs` to convert from STDIN to a list of arguments.  Be sure to use `gzip -k` to avoid deleting the original file.

```
git diff --name-only <revision> | grep '.css$' - | xargs gzip -k
```

Repeat for each file extension.

> Sync all changed js files, sync all of changed css files separately.

Pass the appropriate `--include` filter into `aws s3 sync`. For CSS it's `*.css.gz`.

You'll probably want to clean these files up with `git clean -dxf`.

> Copy files that have changed and that are in the images/ folder to a another directory

Again using `git diff --name-only` and `xargs` but this time just on the `images/` directory.  Use `cp -t <destination>` to copy the list from xargs to your destination directory.

```
git diff --name-only <revision> images/ | xargs cp -t <destination dir>
```

Comment: these commands are not working for me. For example for the last command, I get the error: cp: missing file operand

Comment: cp (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Torbjörn Granlund, David MacKenzie, and Jim Meyering.

Comment: @Jasmine That probably means there are no changed files.

Comment: @Jasmine Then your `git diff` command is not producing a file list. You might need to supply it with a `revision`. If it's since the last push, it would probably be `origin/master` or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsfiles=()
cssfiles=()
htmlfiles=()
imagesfiles=()

# Loop over the output from `git diff --name-only -z` to operate by file.
while IFS= read -r -d '' file || [ -n "$file" ]; do
    # gzip the '.js', '.css' and '.html' in place while looping
    # also set up the arrays as valid arguments (hopefully) for the 'aws s3 sync' commands later.
    case "$file" in
        *.js)
            gzip "$file" && mv "$file"{.gz,} && jsfiles+=(--include "$file")
            ;;
        *.css)
            gzip "$file" && mv "$file"{.gz,} && cssfiles+=(--include "$file")
            ;;
        *.html)
            gzip "$file" && mv "$file"{.gz,} && htmlfiles+=(--include "$file")
            ;;
        images/*)
            imagesfiles+=("$file")
            ;;
    esac
done <(git diff --name-only -z "$revision")

aws s3 sync . s3://test --content-type "JS" --cache-control "max-age=31536000" --exclude "*" "${jsfiles[@]}"
aws s3 sync . s3://test --content-type "CSS" --cache-control "max-age=31536000" --exclude "*" "${cssfiles[@]}"
aws s3 sync . s3://test --content-type "text/html" --cache-control "max-age=31536000" --exclude "*" "${htmlfiles[@]}"

cp "${imagesfiles[@]}" "$some_other_dir/"
```